# data is not submitting into db

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I’m trying to signup user, initially it was working but now its not , when i enter data and click on signup then nothing happens, any solution to resolve this issue?

this is UsersController:

```
  public function register(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all();
        /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;*/
        // Check if User already exists
        $usersCount = User::where('email',$data['email'])->count();
        if($usersCount>0){
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error','Email already exists!');
        }else{

            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $data['name'];
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
            $user->save();

            // Send Confirmation Email
            $email = $data['email'];
            $messageData = ['email'=>$data['email'],'name'=>$data['name'],'code'=>base64_encode($data['email'])];
            Mail::send('emails.confirmation',$messageData,function($message) use($email){
                $message->to($email)->subject('Confirm your E-com Account');
            });

            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Please confirm your email to activate your account!');

            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']])){
                Session::put('frontSession',$data['email']);

                if(!empty(Session::get('session_id'))){
                    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
                    DB::table('cart')->where('session_id',$session_id)->update(['user_email' => $data['email']]);
                }

                return redirect('/cart');
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

this is registeration form:

```
  <form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" action="{{ url('/user-register') }}" method="POST">{{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    <input id="myPassword" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
                </form>
```

and this is route:

```
Route::post('/user-register','UsersController@register');
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: nthing..........

Comment: Does your form is taking you to register method? or its posting only.

Comment: its doing nthing, signup button isnt working

Comment: Can you see any error in your browser  console ?

Comment: ```<input type="submit" value="submit"/>```. try this by replacing ```<button>``` tag

Comment: no, nthing appears

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... thnx now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The basic registration method in laravel with validation and auto login

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',

    ]);


    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
     Auth::login($user);
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')
                    ->with('success','Congratulation !!! You are registered successfully. Now you can login');
   }
```

What  is the error you will see in the blade template by adding this before form

```
  @if($errors->all())
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
      @endforeach
  @endif
```

Comment: still same issue, i think the problem is with signup form not with controller

Comment: you can debug in controller whether you are getting data in controller or not. And you can use input  type submit instead of button type submit.